# Возможно ли перехватывать пакеты с сетевого устройства, до обработки их ядром?

Tags: linux, сеть, kernel

Проблема:
Имеется некоторое медленное (процессор) устройство с 1Гбит сетевой картой.
Было написано приложение UDP эхо сервер.
При исследовании было обнаружено, что после прохождения определенного количества пакетов, начинаются их массовые потери, т.е. если отправлено 500, то вернулось 200 первых (пакеты маркировались), остальные потеряны.
Из чего был сделан вывод, что ядро копит быстро поступающие пакеты, пока не заполнит свои буфера, и только затем отдаёт их приложению на обработку.
Можно ли изменить такое поведение ядра?

Далее был написан небольшой модуль ядра, использующий перехват dev_add_pack, ситуация почти не изменилась, т.к. перехватчик получает пакеты из очереди сообщений.

Задача:
Перехватывать и фильтровать пакеты до помещения их в очередь ядра, и по возможности (не обязательное условие, можно решить иначе) обрабатывать и отправлять обратно.

Вопрос: 
Какие ещё низкоуровневые способы перехвата пакетов существуют кроме dev_add_pack, nf_register_hook, переписывания драйвера сетевого устройства ?

Comment: Изменить на какое именно? Не обращать внимания на аппаратные прерывания, вместо этого передавая управление приложению?

Comment: Прерывание обрабатывает одно ядро, приложение может пробудиться на другом, но этого не происходит, пока очередь не "захлебнётся" пакетами.

Comment: Двухъядерный, но *медленный* процессор? Странная проблема. Надеюсь, из-за русских «ядер» у нас дополнительного недопонимания не возникнет ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиски на просторах интернета дали следующую информацию.
Существуют такие компоненты:
[netmap](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/) - основная часть является модулем ядра, предоставляет приложениям из пользовательского пространства работать с ring-буферами драйвера напрямую, что уменьшает накладные расходы на множественное копирование данных, но работать приходиться с сырыми пакетами. 
Из минусов: поддерживает ограниченный набор драйверов сетевых устройств. Т.к. пакеты перехватывает у модифицированных драйверов, а не из ядра.
[Пояснения и схема взаимодействия с ядром, стеком и приложением](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329527/c-tcp-netmap-could-tun-tap-interface-neglict-the-use-of-netmap?answertab=votes#tab-top), были найдены в английской версии SO.

[PF_RING](http://www.ntop.org/products/packet-capture/pf_ring/) - Аналог netmap, но со своими особенностями, подробно отличия не изучал.

[Intel DPDK](http://dpdk.org/) как понял, для карт Intel, [презентация](http://www.intel.ru/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/presentation/dpdk-packet-processing-ia-overview-presentation.pdf)

Итого: пакеты можно перехватывать до получения их ядром, но для этого потребуется вмешательство в исходный код драйвера сетевой карты, либо использовать вышеуказанные пакеты, в них это уже сделано.

Comment: Интересно. А вообще, скажем, tshark тоже захлебывается? Насколько знаю, она использует raw socket в user mode и получает доступ к пакетам до их попадания в очередь порта. Попробуйте, может это окажется более простым подходом.

Comment: Думаю что RAW  socket не спасёт, т.к. он только позволит получать копии, а ядро будет продолжать отвлекаться на мусорные пакеты.  dev_add_pack - ниже некуда без модификации ядерной части. Можно попробовать nf_register_hook, там можно дропать пакеты, не давая их обрабатывать далее модулям стека протоколов IP.

Comment: Только копии -- это верно. Но вам-то для реализации такого udp echo этого вроде бы и достаточно. Получили RAW копию -- отправили нормальный udp ответ.  Собственно, в таком случае сами udp-пакеты можно и не получать (порт вообще не слушать, ядро будет загружаться по-минимому).